# How works in CAML Data field like NoW and Today, and adding range + One month

Tags: development

I take create on U2U a Calm Query with adding a dates + 1 Month, or minus one month. How will this Query will works?

`<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='DataPoc' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>[2012-11-18 22:46:28+1Month(s)]</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='DataKon' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>[2012-11-18 22:47:15-1Month(s)]</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an offset in the CAML query, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460496.aspx. For example,

```
<Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created"/><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-30"/></Value></Geq></Where></Query>
```